# BASIC line input buffer location on ZX Spectrum

Tags: emulation, zx-spectrum

I'm currently writing a ZX Spectrum emulator (I know there are plenty, but it's a project).

I'm having an issue where it keeps repeating the last key press even though I know the port lines have been reset.

This is what it looks like: [ZXE Keyboard Shenanigans](https://youtu.be/Qps1_Ub2_Uc)
(in this recording, I pressed <kbd>C</kbd> once).

It might be helpful if I could know the location in memory where the Speccy stores lines of BASIC being entered, so I could see what's updating that.

Comment: If I knew the answer, I’d just tell you, but as I don’t then all I can offer is that [this lengthy, commented disassembly of the 48kb ROM](https://archive.org/details/CompleteSpectrumROMDisassemblyThe/mode/1up) is fantastic.

Comment: This is pretty good also, but I can't find what I'm looking for. https://skoolkid.github.io/rom/index.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's all in the original ZX Spectrum user manual.

[Chapter 24 'The Memory'](https://worldofspectrum.org/ZXBasicManual/zxmanchap24.html) details the various memory areas maintained by ZX BASIC, including the memory format of a BASIC line and of the various types of variables.

[Chapter 25 'System Variables'](https://worldofspectrum.org/ZXBasicManual/zxmanchap25.html) lists the various system variables, some of which are the start addresses of the various memory areas.

- 16-bit start address of BASIC line being edited is stored in `E_LINE` at address 23641 (0x5C59).
- 16-bit end address of BASIC line being edited is `WORKSP`-1.
- 16-bit address `WORKSP` is stored at address 23649 (0x5C61).

You'll find the below diagram of memory allocation in chapter 24.

[image]

Comment: Ooh. That looks promising! Thanks... will investigate and accept the answer if it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

The keyboard subroutines move the last key that has been pressed into the system variable LAST_K ($5C08).

The KSTATE array (the 8 bytes before LAST_K, $5C00-5C07) are an array of two sets of 4-byte entries that are used for keyboard de-bounce and key repeat triggering.